# jQuery - PHP - link href to other page ID not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a PHP site, with a nav that has links to ID's (sections) on the home page. When you click on the link it scrolls down to that section, and everything works how it's supposed to.

However, the nav also has links to other pages, and if you aren't on the home page, and you click on one of these ID hrefs, it doesn't scroll down to that section, it just goes to the top of the homepage.

I tried adding home.php#idname or ./#idname in the href, but neither seem to work. I'm guessing that I might need to get the baseUrl and add that to the href somehow, but I'm not sure. My Javascript/jQuery isn't the best.

How do I make the ID links go and scroll to the desired section, when you're on another page? I've looked up tons of related topics, and nothing seems to be working.

Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#navm li a').click(function(e) {

  var href = $(this).attr('href');

  var autoScrollPosition = parseInt($(href).offset().top - $('#header').outerHeight());

  if (window.location.hash) {

    $(scrollCheck).stop().animate({
      scrollTop: autoScrollPosition
    }, {
      duration: 750,
      easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
      queue: false,
      complete: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          enable_scroll();
        }, 50);
      }
    });

  }

});

});
```

```html
<div id="navm">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#description" rel="nofollow">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#specification" rel="nofollow">Specification</a></li>
    <li><a href="#downloads" rel="nofollow">Downloads</a></li>
    <li class="insight">Insights<span></span>
      <ul class="articles-nav">
        <li><a href="insights/">Article 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="description"></div>

<div id="specification"></div>

<div id="downloads"></div>
```

Comment: why do you feel that this is a "php" question?

Comment: Because it's a php site, and all the pages are set up like: page_home.php etc. So I thought maybe the code inside the href will need to be called differently.

Comment: Dont bind to `#navm li a` then but rather a class

Comment: Sounds like you want to be running your Javascript code (or a slight variation of it) on page load, as well as on nav click.  That way you handle the case of navigating to a different page, not just a different section on the same page.

Comment: Ok. I should've said I have my jQuery code inside of $(document).ready. I've updated my code. I'll try on page load too. Thanks

Comment: @bevstar7 My point is that you want the scroll-to-hash logic both within and outside of your nav click handler.  That handler will have no effect when navigating to a new page.  So you need to have code on the new page that will handle the scrolling.

Comment: This is basic built-in browser functionality. E.g. [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#refsect1-domdocument.loadhtml-examples) will scroll to the examples section.

Comment: I put the code inside of the page load, and it still doesn't work.